# Field values are being fetched as null while reading the data with SolrContentSearchManager with Solr custom FlatDataCrawler

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm busy creating a Crawler using `FlatDataCrawler` for custom non-sitecore data.
Inserting the data into Solr works, but when i'm reading the data with `SolrContentSearchManager` my entities are inserted with null field values.

I debugged through Sitecore pdb's to find where Sitecore initializes my custom objects (inherited from `IIndexable`) when I use `IProviderSearchContext` (This is the `CreateElementInstance` method in the `DefaultDocumentMapper` class.)

My field values are available when I debug, but `IIndexDocumentPropertyMapperObjectFactory` is null so it would never insert these values in my object.

See here:
In my configuration I use the same `indexDocumentPropertyMapper` configuration as the default Solr configuration.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information?  The code snippet above doesn't give me enough information.  Can you post snippets of your crawler?  Does it inherit from HierarchicalDataCrawler<T> or Crawler<T>?

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. I used `fieldNameFormat="PREFIX_{0}"` in my `fieldMap`.
This way Sitecore couldn't map my object to the Solr object.